# Switching between the cases using addOnItemTouchListener

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have two activities, `FirstActivity` and `SecondActivity`.

In `FirstActivity`, I have two cases;  `case 1`and `case 2`;

And in `SecondActivity`, I have `recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener` event defined.

What I am trying to do is, when recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener is initialized, or when i touch any item; the `case 1` will be called, else `case 2`. Can someone help me on this?

Thnk you in advance

Answer (score 0):

**Easy way:**

Have a static boolean variable in Application class. Change that boolean value if you touch the item in SecondActivity. Check the boolean value in the FirstActivity to decide which case will run.

**Correct way:**

Have a boolean member variable in the SecondActivity. Change that boolean value if you touch the item in SecondActivity. Send that boolean to the FirstActivity through onActivityResult. Check the boolean value in the FirstActivity to decide which case will run.

**Another correct way:**

Save a boolean in the SharedPreferences from the SecondActivity. Get the boolean value from the SharedPreferences in the FirstActivity and check the boolean to decide which case will run.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you could do it is by creating a custom touch listener class. I did that for one of my apps.

```
    public final class CustomTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    Context context;

    public CustomTouchListener(Context context) {
        super();
        this.context = context;

    }


    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            //case 1 code here

            return false;
        }else{
            //case 2 code here
        }

        return true;

    }
}
```

Then you would call:

```
recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new CustomTouchListener(this));
```